# Given different start and end dates, find the daily average of each variable

Tags: r, date, average

I have data with varying start and end dates.

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), start=c("2010/01/01","2010/01/01","2010/01/02"), end=c("2010/01/01","2010/01/05","2010/01/03"), a=c(140,750,56),b=c(48,25,36))
mydata

  id      start        end   a  b
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-01 140 48
2  2 2010-01-01 2010-01-05 750 25
3  3 2010-01-02 2010-01-03  56 36
```

I want to find the average of the variables *a* and *b* for each day. Below I execute it by expanding every row with different start and end dates, then collapsing it back to the daily level.

```
mydata$subt <- as.numeric(as.Date(mydata$end, "%Y/%m/%d") - as.Date(mydata$start, "%Y/%m/%d") + 1)

require(data.table) 
mydata <- setDT(mydata)[ , list(idnum = id, date = seq(start, end, by = "day"), a=a/subt, b=b/subt), by = 1:nrow(mydata)]
mydata

   nrow idnum       date   a  b
1:    1     1 2010-01-01 140 48
2:    2     2 2010-01-01 150  5
3:    2     2 2010-01-02 150  5
4:    2     2 2010-01-03 150  5
5:    2     2 2010-01-04 150  5
6:    2     2 2010-01-05 150  5
7:    3     3 2010-01-02  28 18
8:    3     3 2010-01-03  28 18

mydata %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(a = sum(a),
            b = sum(b))
```

Desired Outcome:

```
  date           a     b
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2010-01-01   290    53
2 2010-01-02   178    23
3 2010-01-03   178    23
4 2010-01-04   150     5
5 2010-01-05   150     5
```

However, I have plenty of rows with different start and end dates, and sometimes the length of difference is very long. I am wondering if there is an easier way (i.e., without expanding every row) to find the daily averages for each variable. It would also be great if there is a way to find the weekly averages without first finding the daily figures. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We convert the 'start' 'end' columns to `Date` class with `ymd` (from `lubridate`), create a `seq`uence of dates from 'start' to 'end' for corresponding elements with `map2`, `mutate` the 'a', 'b' by dividing them with the `lengths` of the `list` column 'date', `unnest` the 'date' and grouped by 'date' we get the `sum` of 'a', 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
mydata %>%
     mutate(across(c(start, end), ymd)) %>% 
     transmute(id, date = map2(start, end, seq, by = 'day'), a, b) %>% 
     mutate(across(c(a, b), ~ ./lengths(date)))  %>%
     unnest(date) %>%
     group_by(date) %>% 
     summarise(across(c(a, b), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  date           a     b
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2010-01-01   290    53
#2 2010-01-02   178    23
#3 2010-01-03   178    23
#4 2010-01-04   150     5
#5 2010-01-05   150     5
```

Comment: I receive this error:
Error in across(c(start, end), ymd) : could not find function "across"
Any ideas why it might be?

Comment: @mazbata can you show the error.  I am using the newest version of `dplyr`. Can you please update your dplyr version if it is < 1.0.0

Comment: `across` is introduced from `dplyr` >= 1.0.0.  Can you please update your package version